# How can I translate SQL to Excel formulas?

Tags: microsoft-excel, sql

I have an excel sheet with raw data and I want make a custom view on it in another table for reporting purposes.

How can I translate the following pseudo code to Excel?

```
select ColA, ColB, ColC from SheetA where (SheetA.ColD in ("x","y","z") or SheetA.ColE in ("1","2","3"))
```

I am looking for a solution along the lines of VLOOKUP MATCH and INDEX.

Comment: Are you connecting to a Database from inside Excel? If so, you can use that query

Comment: No i get a dumped file.

Comment: In that case, if you have the data, select it all, and add filters (or better, click on insert, and select table and select My Table Has Headers). From here, you can filter and perform the same thing

Comment: I specifically want to separate data from view. In Addition i have implemented the x,y,z as named range.

Comment: In Excel 2010 (and others), you can create queries to Excel files. In the Data ribbon's "Get External Data" section (on the left), choose "From Other Sources" and then "From Microsoft Query". You should already have a data source setup for "Excel Files" so start there, try some things, and come back if you get stuck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Copied from the comments: In Excel 2010 (and others), you can create queries to Excel files. In the Data ribbon's "Get External Data" section (on the left), choose "From Other Sources" and then "From Microsoft Query". You should already have a data source setup for "Excel Files". After that, you can build something in MS Query that will work.

---

If you really want a formula response, you're going to have to deal with some mess. First, the most important step to make it *loads* easier is to add a field to your original data to handle the `WHERE` statement. I'm going to call that `ColF` and its formula will probably look something like this:

```
=SUM(IFERROR(MATCH([@ColD],x,0),0),IFERROR(MATCH([@ColD],y,0),0),IFERROR(MATCH([@ColD],z,0),0),IFERROR(MATCH([@ColE],range1,0),0),IFERROR(MATCH([@ColE],range2,0),0),IFERROR(MATCH([@ColE],range3,0),0))>0
```

For your custom view, you need to create another table that has the same number of rows as the original. In addition to `ColA`, `ColB`, `ColC`, you might want a field to help with the lookup. You can put the formula inside each column but that's just bloat for no reason and will slow the calculations. The lookup portion looks like this (note that it's an array formula entered with `CTRL`+`ALT`+`ENTER`):

```
{=IFERROR(SMALL(IF(Table1[ColF],ROW(Table1[ColF])),ROW()-1),"")}
```

That will be a list of all the row numbers from your original data that meet the criteria as defined by the formula in `ColF`. There will be some number of blanks at the end. The next few fields are just `INDEX` based on `Row`.

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(Table1[ColA],[@Row]-1),"")
=IFERROR(INDEX(Table1[ColB],[@Row]-1),"")
=IFERROR(INDEX(Table1[ColC],[@Row]-1),"")
```

There's your table. You'll have to deal with the blank rows at the bottom through whatever means you like. Autofilter would work just fine. As I indicated earlier, you can get rid of the `Row` field by making your other formulas longer array formulas:

```
{=IFERROR(INDEX(Table1[ColA],SMALL(IF(Table1[ColF],ROW(Table1[ColF])),ROW()-1)-1),"")}
```

... but that'll slow things down.

Comment: Still I would like a pure Excel formula answer, just for curiosity...

Comment: +1 just for understanding what the question meant